# Proper way to wrap selectively class instances (or "lift" functions like `sortBy`, `minimumBy`, ... automatically)

Tags: haskell, category-theory

Let some type instanced to many classes. What is the proper way to replace, selectively, certain instances's behaviors?

One way to express it could be construct the `by` operator then

```
data Person ...

sort personList              -- default Ord instance
(sort `by` age) personList   -- `age` modify `Ord` instance
```

here, `sort` could be any function (e.g. `minimum`) with any arity (e.g. `insert`).

If we have a function like

```
reportPersons :: [Person] -> Report
```

and it functions use `Ord` (to sort list), `Show` (to format records), ... or other especific instances; using `funcBy` pattern we must to write

```
reportPersonsBy :: (Person -> Person -> Ordering) -> (Person -> String) -> ... -> [Person] -> Report
```

but we can use `by` to wrap each behavior with original `reportPersons` **without refactor `reportPersonsBy`** (explained example and not solved related problems at the end).

My toy (and not fully satisfactory) solution is (complete code at the end):

A class to wrap types into types to override instances

```
class Wrappable m where
    wrap   :: forall a . a -> m a
    unwrap :: forall a . m a -> a
```

and `by` function to wrap functions

```
-- wrap functions: f a -> g a
by :: (Functor f, Functor g, Wrappable m) => (f (m a) -> g (m a)) -> m a -> f a -> g a
by f _ = fmap unwrap . f . fmap wrap

-- wrap functions: a -> f a -> g a
by_ f m a = f (wrap a) `by` m
```

Now we can write (at the bottom complete example)

```
-- f a -> f a
mapM_ print $  sort           personList
mapM_ print $ (sort `by` age) personList

-- f a -> g a
print $  minimum           personList
print $ (minimum `by` age) personList

-- a -> f a -> f a
print $  insert            jane personList
print $ (insert `by_` age) jane personList
```

Ok, `by`, `by_`, ... works but, what is the **correct way**? how write complete polymorphic `by`?

I've tried but not work

```
class Wrappable m => By m x f i o where
    by :: f m x -> m x -> i m x -> o m x
```

to be able to write function instances as

```
instance (Wrappable m, Functor f, Functor g) => By m a (f (m a) -> g (m a)) (f a) (g a) where
    by :: (f (m a) -> g (m a)) -> m a -> f a -> g a
    by f _ = fmap unwrap . f . fmap wrap
```

Thank you!

**Report example**

Suppose exists one report function for persons (**wrappable persons**)

```
reportPersons :: (Wrappable m, Show (m Person), Ord (m Person)) => [m Person] -> Maybe String
reportPersons = Just . unlines . map show . sort
```

with carried behaviors for each instance (`Ord` and `Show`).

Let (not polymorphic `by` :( )

```
by' :: (Functor f, Functor g, Wrappable m) => (f (m a) -> g b) -> m a -> f a -> g b
by' f _ = f . fmap wrap
```

and a new `Wrappable` instance for `Person`s

```
newtype Format1 a = Format1 a deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance Show (Format1 Person) where show (Format1 (Person n a)) = "Name := " ++ n ++ " (" ++ show a ++ " years old)"
format1 :: Format1 Person; format1 = undefined
instance Wrappable Format1 where  wrap               = Format1
                                  unwrap (Format1 p) = p
```

now, we can report persons overlapping selectively behaviors

```
putStrLn $ fromJust $ (reportPersons `by'` age)     personList
putStrLn $ fromJust $ (reportPersons `by'` format1) personList
```

with output

```
ByAge (Person {personName = "John", personAge = 16})
ByAge (Person {personName = "Anne", personAge = 24})
ByAge (Person {personName = "Zorn", personAge = 37})
ByAge (Person {personName = "Peter", personAge = 42})

Name := Anne (24 years old)
Name := John (16 years old)
Name := Peter (42 years old)
Name := Zorn (37 years old)
```

using `TypeFamilies` or other feature probably, we can chain `Wrappables`, etc... (it's a toy!!! and I don't know how to do in a good way)

(complete sandbox code)

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Maybe
import Prelude hiding (minimum)
import Data.List hiding (minimum)
import System.Random

{- safe minimum -}
minimum [] = Nothing; minimum xs = listToMaybe $ sort xs

data Person = Person { personName :: String, personAge :: Int } deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

personList = [Person "Anne" 24, Person "John" 16, Person "Peter" 42, Person "Zorn" 37]
jane       =  Person "Jane" 26


class Wrappable m where
    wrap   :: forall a . a -> m a
    unwrap :: forall a . m a -> a

-- wrap functions: f a -> g a
by :: (Functor f, Functor g, Wrappable m) => (f (m a) -> g (m a)) -> m a -> f a -> g a
by f _ = fmap unwrap . f . fmap wrap

-- wrap functions: a -> f a -> g a
by_ f m a = f (wrap a) `by` m

newtype ByAge a = ByAge a deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Ord (ByAge Person) where (ByAge (Person _ a)) `compare` (ByAge (Person _ b)) = a `compare` b
age :: ByAge Person; age = undefined
instance Wrappable ByAge where  wrap             = ByAge
                                unwrap (ByAge p) = p

main = do

    -- f a -> f a
    mapM_ print $  sort           personList
    mapM_ print $ (sort `by` age) personList

    -- f a -> g a
    print $  minimum           personList
    print $ (minimum `by` age) personList

    -- a -> f a -> f a
    print $  insert            jane personList
    print $ (insert `by_` age) jane personList
```

Comment: By a quick look you seem to be reinventing Lenses or something.

Comment: Shouldn't functions like `sortBy` eliminate the problem? Just curious. Your solution seems OK for the cases when there's no `...By` function. Though first-class instances could be nice.

Comment: @n.m. With N functions and M criteria you must to write NxM new functions (`funcCriteria`) instead only M `Wrappable` instances (`func 'by' criteria`).

Comment: How? Do you know what `sortBy` does? It's in the Prelude.

Comment: Ok @n.m. the problem with first class is you must to known the function shape (a deep use of `sortBy` must to carry the criteria). E.g. with `Person` you must to carry `compare 'on' field` but `Wrappable` carry automatically the exact instance for each case. Think on a `reportPersonList`, with `sortBy` you must to carry all "configuration report" like `sortCriteria`.

Comment: @Jefffrey can you do descending sort or case-insensitive sort with lenses?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You must supply criteria one way or another, i.e. `sortBy criterion` vs `sort ``by`` criterion`. What's the advantage of your type of criterion?

Comment: @n.m. "What's the advantage of your type of criterion?" -- That you can reuse and compose the `sort`, `minimum`, etc... functions I guess.

Comment: Hm, I don't see how you do that *without refactoring* `reportPersons`. Can you show an example?

Comment: @n.m. I can sort persons by age without refactoring `sort` function. That is the example. I can modify (a posteriori) all (wrappables) instances used by any function (like `reportPersons`) without modify that function.

Comment: You don't need to refactor `sort` because it has already been refactored for you. `sortBy` is in the Prelude, just use it.

Comment: @n.m. "Can you show an example?" done! "it has already been refactored for you" but I still carrying criteria into the deep...

Comment: I do observe refactoring here. You have modified `reportPersons`. Instead of `[Person]` it now accepts `[m Person]` with some constraints on `m`. The difference between that new `reportPersons` and `reportPersonsBy` is syntactic sugar (yes, type classes are syntactic sugar), only it looks like this sugar is somewhat harder to swallow than the original pill.

Comment: @n.m. No, no, that `reportPersons` is the first implementation of one **Wrappable** function reporting persons. This function is prior to and unknown the "a posteriori" `ByAge` and `Format1` implementations. (when I wrote the first `reportPerson` shape I unknown the possible "real" solution).

Comment: You have two constraints of interest in the implementation of `reportPersons`: `Show (m Person)` and `Ord (m Person)`. They exactly correspond to the two extra arguments of `reportPersonsBy`---a function you could have started with, without either bothering with `reportPersons` or going to all this trouble with type classes. What exactly does your function allow that `reportPersonsBy` doesn't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67327/discussion-between-josejuan-and-n-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible valid way.

Let our data type

```
data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int
                     } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

to grant overload selectively (and interdependently) instances we only need

```
class CPerson p where
    get :: p -> Person -- grant access to real data

instance CPerson Person where
    get = id
```

now, let any function **without** specify explicitly behaviors (like `sortBy` vs. `sort`)

```
reportPersons :: (Ord p, Show p, CPerson p) => [p] -> IO ()
reportPersons = mapM_ print . sort
```

with that, we can only report ordering by name and showing with default `Show` data instance

```
Person {name = "Alice", age = 24}
Person {name = "Anne", age = 16}
Person {name = "Peter", age = 16}
Person {name = "Pluto", age = 24}
```

*A posteriori* we need sort that report using any other field (eg. `age`), **without modify** (we won't, we can't, ...) `reportPersons` function we can do writing

```
-- Wrap our inner `CPerson`
newtype OrdByAge p = OrdByAge p deriving Eq -- Eq is invariant over wrapping

-- Grant access to other wrappers to final data
instance CPerson p => CPerson (OrdByAge p) where
    get (OrdByAge q) = get q

-- `Show` maybe or not invariant over wrapping, then bypass
instance (Show p, CPerson p) => Show (OrdByAge p) where
    show = show . get

-- `Ord` instance modification to sort by age
instance (Eq p, CPerson p) => Ord (OrdByAge p) where
    (OrdByAge a) `compare` (OrdByAge b) = (age $ get a) `compare` (age $ get b)
```

now, we can use the unmodified `reportPersons` ordering by `age`

```
reportPersons $ personList `as` OrdByAge
```

with result

```
Person {name = "Peter", age = 16}
Person {name = "Anne", age = 16}
Person {name = "Alice", age = 24}
Person {name = "Pluto", age = 24}
```

now, we won sort by `age` then by `name`, again without modify `reportPersons`

```
newtype ThenByName p = ThenByName p deriving (Show, Eq)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (ThenByName p) where
    get (ThenByName q) = get q

-- Using the chained instance to compare first by inner then by our instance
instance (Eq q, Ord q, CPerson q) => Ord (ThenByName q) where
    (ThenByName a) `compare` (ThenByName b) =
        case a `compare` b of
            EQ -> (name $ get a) `compare` (name $ get b)
            x  -> x
```

we can write many different instance versions, e.g. two different format instances

```
-- Short format:
newtype ShortFormat p = ShortFormat p deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (ShortFormat p) where
    get (ShortFormat q) = get q
instance CPerson p => Show (ShortFormat p) where
    show p = (name $ get p) ++ " (" ++ (show $ age $ get p) ++ " years old)"

-- Long format:
newtype LongFormat p = LongFormat p deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (LongFormat p) where
    get (LongFormat q) = get q
instance CPerson p => Show (LongFormat p) where
    show p = "Person:\n\tName: " ++ (name $ get p) ++ "\n\tAge: " ++ (show $ age $ get p)
```

and mix instances as we prefer, e.g. we can get a new `modifiedReport` as

```
let modifiedReport = reportPersons ~> OrdByAge
                                   .> ThenByName
                                   .> LongFormat

modifiedReport personList
```

with result

```
Person:
    Name: Anne
    Age: 16
Person:
    Name: Peter
    Age: 16
Person:
    Name: Alice
    Age: 24
Person:
    Name: Pluto
    Age: 24
```

(Complete sandbox code)

```
import Data.List

data Person = Person { name :: String
                     , age  :: Int
                     } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

class CPerson p where
    get :: p -> Person

instance CPerson Person where
    get = id

reportPersons :: (Ord p, Show p, CPerson p) => [p] -> IO ()
reportPersons = mapM_ print . sort

personList = [ Person "Peter" 16
             , Person "Alice" 24
             , Person "Pluto" 24
             , Person "Anne"  16
             ]

newtype OrdByAge p = OrdByAge p deriving Eq
instance CPerson p => CPerson (OrdByAge p) where
    get  (OrdByAge q) = get q
instance (Eq p, CPerson p) => Ord (OrdByAge p) where
    (OrdByAge a) `compare` (OrdByAge b) = (age $ get a) `compare` (age $ get b)
instance (Show p, CPerson p) => Show (OrdByAge p) where
    show = show . get

newtype ShortFormat p = ShortFormat p deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (ShortFormat p) where
    get (ShortFormat q) = get q
instance CPerson p => Show (ShortFormat p) where
    show p = (name $ get p) ++ " (" ++ (show $ age $ get p) ++ " years old)"

newtype ThenByName p = ThenByName p deriving (Show, Eq)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (ThenByName p) where
    get (ThenByName q) = get q
instance (Eq q, Ord q, CPerson q) => Ord (ThenByName q) where
    (ThenByName a) `compare` (ThenByName b) =
        case a `compare` b of
            EQ -> (name $ get a) `compare` (name $ get b)
            x  -> x

newtype LongFormat p = LongFormat p deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance CPerson p => CPerson (LongFormat p) where
    get (LongFormat q) = get q
instance CPerson p => Show (LongFormat p) where
    show p = "Person:\n\tName: " ++ (name $ get p) ++ "\n\tAge: " ++ (show $ age $ get p)

xs `as` q = fmap q xs

f ~> q = f . fmap q  ; infixr 7 ~>
p .> q = q . p       ; infixr 8 .>

main = do

    reportPersons personList

    reportPersons $ personList `as` OrdByAge

    reportPersons $ personList `as` OrdByAge
                               `as` ThenByName
                               `as` ShortFormat

    let modifiedReport = reportPersons ~> OrdByAge
                                       .> ThenByName
                                       .> LongFormat

    modifiedReport personList
```

Answer (score 2):

> Let some type instanced to many classes. What is the proper way to
>   replace, selectively, certain instances's behaviors?

The proper way is to use plain old functions and use `sortBy`, `maximumBy`, `groupBy` etc. instead.

I think this is abuse of typeclasses. Keep it simple, stupid! Yes, this is opinion-based, let stackoverflow's voting system sort(By) it out.

Comment: With N functions and M criteria you must to write NxM new functions (`funcCriteria`) instead only M `Wrappable` instances (`func 'by' criteria`). And more, you can generalize other functions like `sort 'by' name 'then' age`, `minimums 'by' name 'then' age`, ... without write new functions for each combination.

Comment: I've updated question comparing with `funcBy` pattern.